# Calculate product of last x days - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table with dates and numbers

```
SELECT [Fecha], number
FROM table
```

And I need to calculate some products of the last 30,60 and 90 days, so the final results looks like (I need it in a view)

```
fecha, number, Product_of_number_last_30_days
```

(Product of last 30 days is ALL the numbers between the date and date-30)

Thanks

Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00 (Service Pack 2)

(I do not need to SUM i need to MULTIPLY) thanks!

Comment: what database and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate what RDBMS you have, for SQL SERVER:

```
SELECT SUM(NUMBER)
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN GETDATE() -30 AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: This might not trap everything, as your getdate will include a time stamp.  If you were to run it RIGHT NOW, it would have a 2pm CST time stamp, which means this query will get everything between 07/13/2014, @ 2pm and 8/13/2014 @ 2pm.   You'd miss all the data between midnight and 1:59pm that initial day.  You are right though on verifying which database he's in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do:

```
Declare @DaysPast int
set @DaysPast = 30

select EXP(sum(log(thisNumber))) 
from CheckThis
where thisDate > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-@DaysPast,101)
```

Check the SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50a86a/7).